# I'm a Designer and Programmer who wants to create some software for photographers

Tags: software, lightroom, web

I've been wanting to use my skills to do some sort of service for Photographers for a while now and thought I'd finally ask.

My initial idea was to create a service that would let you create a beautiful and simple website, without ever leaving Light Room. How do you think that sounds?

If it sounds like a terrible idea, then tell me! And let me know what your big paint points are? What takes ages for you and what do you not like about photography?

Comment: Doesn't Lightroom already have a web gallery feature? Perhaps you could make some themes that extend that?

Comment: I'm not sure. What do you use for your website?

Comment: I host on flickr and share to facebook or twitter or my personal (rarely updated) wordpress blog.

Comment: Ok... What's the best plugin for lightroom that lets you upload images to a service? Do you have a portfolio somewhere on the internet?

Comment: I appreciate the intent, but notice that the [faq] lists "web site development" as off topic.

Comment: I'm not looking to develop a website. I'm looking to solve a problem for photographers with my design and coding skills.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly a 'service' and if you're more into web programming and design, then this may not be your cup of tea, but how about contributing to [darktable](http://www.darktable.org/)? It's open-source RAW development software written in C++.

Comment: A function that lets users create a beautiful website with the click of a button is not a service? Is there a lot of other services that does this now a days?

Comment: No, no, I meant that stand-alone application like darktable cannot really be called a 'service' :-) Sorry for the confusing inversion in the sentence.

Comment: Arh... hehe. I'm looking a bit more to do something like a service. Something that solves a painpoint photographers have. Let me know if you know some of the painpoints photographers have.

Answer (score 2):

lightroom has a web gallery setup already. Some like it. Some don't.

A number of people have already built add-on plug-ins to do web galleries and similar publishing systems. One of the best known is LRP Portfolio: http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/smccormack/lrbportfolio/

photographer's toolbox is a good resource for starting research on what's out there for lightroom, by the way.

also take a look at Jeffrey Friedl's work, since he's done a lot of plug-ins that interface lightroom to various publishing sites like flickr or smugmug. His export plugins are generally considered the best out there.

http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies

Comment: Interesting. So this hooks up to your domain, so you can upload a quick gallery to show to potential clients?